# SPWebPartManager to hide webparts per user

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Can I use `SPWebPartManager` to hide Web Parts per user programmatically?
Such as: Get the `SPWebPartManager` instance, iterate through the Web Parts, and set `visible = false` depending on the user.
I heard from somewhere there when you set `webpart.visible = false` this sets this for all the users, is this true?

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the Web Part in the user scope in order to update user specific properties. Use the [PersonalizationScope Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/567ey2e9) to open the SPLimitedWebPartManager accordingly:

```
SPWeb web = // ...
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(
                                       "<path to page>",
                                       PersonalizationScope.User))
{
  WebPart wp = mgr.WebParts[<ID of the web part to update>];
  wp.Hidden = true; // hide the web part.
  mgr.SaveChanges(wp);
}
```

**Note:** In order to update a peropery in the `PersonalizationScope.User` the property needs to be marked as personal web part storage (`[WebPartStorage(Storage = Storage.Personal)]`):

MSDN description for the User PersonalizationScope scope:

> When referring to the scope on the WebPartManagercontrol, User scope means that personalization data that is user-specific, as well as personalization data that applies to all users, is loaded for all personalizable controls on a page. Only personalization data that is user-specific can be saved on the page.
>   When referring to the scope associated with a Web Parts control property, User scope indicates that the property can only load and store data applicable to all users when running on a page in Shared scope. However, when the property's control is running on a page in User scope, the property's per-user and all-user data will be loaded and merged. In this case, though, only per-user data will be saved when a page is running in User scope.